# Unit Testing Dates - if not week day

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I have a small method which return true or false if a timestamp is a weekend day i.e. saturday or sunday.

Now i am very new to unit testing and i am trying to write a unit test for this.

In my test case, how would i proceed:

Here is my inital thinking.

```
1. Pick any 1 week from the past and then...
   1.1. Get a timestamp for all 5 week days (mon through fri) and pass each timestamp to the function being tested.  If they all return false then proceed...
   1.2  Get the timestamp for both weekend days and pass each to function being tested.  If they both return true then we know the function is correct.
```

or

```
2  Simply pick 1 weekday from the past and 1 weekend day from the past and test with only those 2 dates
```

Am i correct in either of these approaches or is there a better way to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put several checks into a single test, you will have the problem that you won't know what some of the checks might return when one of the first ones fails. Say the method fails for day #3. Would it work for day #4? This information could be very useful when trying to find the bug.

My approach is to test all values at once. It works like this:

1. Select a date in the past
2. Create a loop which advances the date 8 times by one day
3. Call the method for each date and append the result to a string
4. Create a string with the expected result by looking at a real calendar)
5. Compare the two strings

This way, you can see with a single glance for which dates the method fails.

The other option is to write 8 tests and have each test check a single date.

Tip: Tests like this tend to fail when timezones are introduced. Create more tests which use timestamps that are close to midnight and play with the timezome. Is the result still correct?

Comment: That sounds good.  Your point about timezones concerns me.  Would it best toset a specific timezone before running the test?  Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: The best solution is to one inner test method and run it with different timezones. Note that I'm not using PHP. My date/time framework JodaTime has a method where I can override the system default timezone for a test case.

Comment: I can do this with php also with date_default_timezone_set.  I am currently trying to think of what this will uncover though and what other if any timezones to test with

Comment: As for timezones: Try UTC, one from the US and one from Asia. It will find subtle bugs like Monday 0:30 in New York will be Sunday 12:30 in Beijing.

Comment: I am going to go with your suggestion of writing a test for each day as i think it makes the test code much clearer.  Dumb question: why 8 tests?

Comment: So you can see that it goes back to "false" after a weekend (if you start on Monday). The test could be as low of 4 days (Fr->Mo) but 8 or 10 (two weekends) is better. And if you're using a loop, that would be easy to change.

Comment: ok maybe a loop would be better then.  Do you suggest created a string say $expectedResult = "true-true-true-true-true-false-false" and on each iteration build up a result string and compare with the assertEquals ?

Answer (score 2):

This calls for a [data provider](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) or two. PHPUnit will first call the data provider to get an array containing the data sets it will pass to the test where each data set is an array of parameters to pass to the test method. Next it executes the test once per data set. Here each data set will be a simple date string along with the name of the day for the error message.

```
/**
 * @dataProvider weekdays
 */
function testDetectsWeekdays($date, $day) {
    self::assertTrue($fixture->isWeekday($date), $day);
}

/**
 * @dataProvider weekends
 */
function testDetectsWeekends($date, $day) {
    self::assertFalse($fixture->isWeekday($date), $day);
}

function weekdays() {
    return array(
        array('2012-08-20', 'Monday'),
        array('2012-08-21', 'Tuesday'),
        array('2012-08-22', 'Wednesday'),
        array('2012-08-23', 'Thursday'),
        array('2012-08-24', 'Friday'),
    );
}

function weekends() {
    return array(
        array('2012-08-25', 'Saturday'),
        array('2012-08-26', 'Sunday'),
    );
}
```

As for the dates to test, you will need to think about any corner cases that might arise given your class. Will leap years affect it? Time zones? It depends on the implementation which is part of unit (white box) testing.

Comment: Maybe also add future dates or (depending on the application) dates before 1970 just to be sure. But thats definitely the way to go imho :)